# Display WPF RichTextBox Formatted Text

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have `RichTextBox` and I'm retrieving the formatted text and store it in the database, I want to display the formatted text of the `RichTextBox` into the UI, but I don't want to display it in a `RichTextBox`.
I just want to display it in a way as the text height and width isn't fixed.
I was using `FlowDocumentPageViewer` but it i's consuming a whole page regardless the text width and height, plus it is showing the page navigator.
I'm really sorry, I'm still new in the WPF and I don't have much experience in that.
Any ideas.

My code to display the text in the `FlowDocumentPageViewer`:

```
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(text));
FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();
TextRange targetRange = new TextRange(fd.ContentStart, fd.ContentEnd);
targetRange.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
fdFormattedText.Document = fd;
```

Where the `fdFormattedText` is the `FlowDocumentPageViewer` and the `text` is the Formatted Text

**UPDATE:** I've forgotten to mention that I'm already displaying the whole report in a `FlowDocument`, that means I have a `FlowDocument` containing `FlowDocumentPageViewer`

**UPDATE (2):** I'm sorry my question wasn't clear. What I want to know, if there are any way to display the formatted text other than using `FlowDocumentPageViewer` or `RichTextBox`?

Comment: You want to preserve the format and it's not doing it when you load it in your FlowdocumentPageViewer?

Comment: @lll It's preserving the format, but it is displaying the formatted text in a separate page instead of displaying it alongside with the other components. I need to know if there are any other controls I can use to display the RichTextBox formatted text or not. I'm sorry I wasn't clear in my question, I'm updating it now

Comment: FlowDocumentScrollViewer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer(v=vs.110).aspx  You can make this into no extras.  Your question is not clear.  A FlowDocument is not a control.

Comment: @Blam, Can't quite follow you, would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Elaborate on what?  It is a direct answer to your question.

Comment: @Blam I guess my question is to find something else other than the FlowDocumentScrollViewer, and in the first update I've mentioned that I'm previewing the whole report in a FlowDocument, which is containing that FlowDocumentScrollViewer. Due to other developer working in the project I'm compelled to work using that specific layout (FlowDocument), and hence they have extended the `DocumentPaginator` whenever I'm using the `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`, I'm having the formatted text in a different page. That's why I'm asking for something else rather than using the `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`

Comment: @Blam concerning the clarity of my question, I'm so sorry that I'm not having such expertise, I'm just trying to do my best, and I've already admitted that I'm still new to WPF. I've just known that the `DcoumentPaginator` was extended by other developers, perhaps that would clear things. Anyway so sorry for not having the enough knowledge to ask about information that I don't have and thanks for your help

Comment: The stated question is other than using FlowDocumentPageViewer or RichTextBox?  There is no mention of FlowDocumentScrollViewer in your question nor any of the edits.

Comment: @Blam, it worked perfectly thank you. I removed the inherited classes they made and used your suggestion `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` and finally it works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to use that as the answer.

FlowDocumentScrollViewer